# Как удалять файлы .aux, .log, .synctex.gz и др. при использовании TexStudio

Tags: latex, texstudio

Можно ли удалять автоматически ненужные мне файлы .aux, .log, .synctex.gz и др. после компиляции при использовании TexStudio (или хотя бы изменить директорию их формирования)

Answer (score 0):

Какого-то однозначного решения по этому вопросу не нашёл - обычно люди предлагают написать скрипт, удаляющий определённые файлы, но он будет различаться в зависимости от операционной системы.

Однако, нашёл решение, как отделить .aux файлы (обычно, их больше всего):

1. Меню "Параметры" -> "Конфигурация TeXstudio"
2. Раздел "Команды"
3. Выбрать компилятор, которым Вы пользуетесь (обычно, это PdfLaTeX или XeLaTeX)

Небольшой ликбез: всё написанное в строке - это команда, которая запускает компиляцию документа. Состоит из:

а. Компилятор (и путь до него)

б. Различные опции (начинаются со знака "-", после знака "=" пишется значение, опции отделяются друг от друга пробелом)

в. Маска компилируемого файла `%.tex`

4. Сделать следующие изменения в строке команды, добавив опции:

`-output-directory="<путь до директории>"` - эта опция меняет директорию выходного файла, т.е. файлы PDF будут появляться НЕ в директории с исходниками, а в указанной.

`-aux-directory="<путь до директории>"` - эта опция меняет директорию выходных файлов .aux по аналогичному принципу.

Возможно, существует подобная опция для файлов .log, но я такой информации не нашёл.

<путь до директории> следует заменить на Ваш. Путь может быть, как абсолютным, так и относительным - не имеет значения. (Лучше всё таки относительный, чтобы при работе с другими документами всё файлы не компилировались туда). ВАЖНО: если директория отсутствует - её нужно создать заранее, иначе компилятор выдаст ошибку!

Если что-то пойдет не так и программа перестанет компилировать документ (ошибка в команде или случайное затирание) - справа от строки есть кнопка со стрелкой "Восстановить значение по умолчанию".